# No context menu on Azure WebJobs on deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure WebSite with several WebJobs, on the main WebSite, in the WebJobs panel on Azure Portal I can add a new WebJob trough the menu, and Restart/Stop/Start/Delete a WebJob through the context menu on one.

Problem is - I have a deployment slot on that WebSite, with WebJobs as well, so now on the deployment slot in the WebJobs panel I can add new WebJobs, but I don't have the context menu to do any actions on the existing WebJobs, the only way I can delete or stop them is to do the switch to the main WebSite and do the action there.

Has anybody the same issue?

EDIT: screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Following up on this with the engineering team

Comment: Hey alek - I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. I just created a new deployment slot and pushed my site/webjob code up. It is working fine with the context menu showing up and acting as expected. Could you include a screenshot if it's still not working for you?

Comment: Added the screenshot, no context menu on Chrome and IE

Comment: Very odd. Not a known issue. Could you email me at chrande (at) microsoft (dot) com with your site name? I'll take a look to see if anything odd is up with your site.